# UnitOfWork TransactionScope rollback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am following this guys tut
[Repository Pattern and Unit of Work with Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688929/Repository-Pattern-and-Unit-of)
to learn how to use the repo pattern in conjunction with the Unit of Work pattern.

It's a nice simple tut and explains things but there is one thing that had me stumped: Why in his UnitOfWork does he not have a Rollback method.

At first I thought: "Ha, the silly guy just forgot to do that, no worries ill just do it myself.

1. Add a Rollback void to his IUnitOfWork
2. Implement the new method in the concrete class
3. In the new method just go _transaction.Rollback

but then thats when I realise that TransactionScope doesn't do rollbacks.

Is there something I am missing? Or are Rollbacks not necessary? Won't I then be left with reserved records in my db until they are eventually garbage collected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RollBack is implicit. When the `transactionScope` is disposed without calling the `Complete` method, it rollbacks the transaction

Comment: aaaah, i understand. Then should my uow call _transaction.Dispose() ?

Comment: You must call `_transaction.Dispose` method as soon as your transaction is done

Comment: Normally you should always use the transaction or UoW in `using` statement or in `try ... finally` block. You want to guarantee that their .Dispose() methods are called.